# RequestMapping Not Working with URL with Params (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a request controller that I have written like this:

```
package com.gtt.glbs;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;

@Controller
public class RedirectController {

    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;


    @RequestMapping(value={"/", "/**"})
    public String showRedirectPage(ModelMap model) {

        String restOfTheUrl = new AntPathMatcher().extractPathWithinPattern(httpServletRequest.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE).toString(), httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());

        if (restOfTheUrl.contains("ATC") || restOfTheUrl.contains("cds") || restOfTheUrl.contains("cgs") || restOfTheUrl.contains("LOG") || restOfTheUrl.contains("pmm") || restOfTheUrl.contains("appgui") || restOfTheUrl.contains("userfileadmin")) {
            return "redirect";
        } else {            
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I start the spring boot application. It works for some URLs and not others. Especially with URLs that have a parameter in it or jsp's at the end. For example:

https://127.0.0.1:8443/ATC/ --> works.

https://127.0.0.1:8443/appgui/framework/filemanager --> works.

https://127.0.0.1:8443/appgui/framework/trafficclassification?service=AVPN&vendor=CISCO --> works.

https://127.0.0.1:8443/ATC/buildinfo/index.jsp --> doesn't work.

https://127.0.0.1:8443/pmm/index.jsp?service=AVPN&action=3 --> doesn't work.

[https://127.0.0.1:8443/cgs/cisco/index.jsp?vendor=CISCO&guiMode=predef-->](https://127.0.0.1:8443/cgs/cisco/index.jsp?vendor=CISCO&guiMode=predef--%3E) doesn't work.

For the one's that doesn't work, it tries to redirect to the url in the browser rather than the "redirect" jsp.

[image]

When hit one of the URL that dont work, with debug logs enabled, I see this. It is trying to replace `pmm` with `error`.

```
2022-05-17 19:55:11.612 DEBUG 19740 --- [io-8443-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error?service=AVPN&action=3", parameters={masked}
2022-05-17 19:55:11.613 DEBUG 19740 --- [io-8443-exec-10] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2022-05-17 19:55:11.632 DEBUG 19740 --- [io-8443-exec-10] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2022-05-17 19:55:11.632 DEBUG 19740 --- [io-8443-exec-10] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'error', model {timestamp=Tue May 17 19:55:11 IST 2022, status=404, error=Not Found, message=JSP file [/pmm/index.jsp] not found, path=/pmm/index.jsp}
2022-05-17 19:55:11.633 DEBUG 19740 --- [io-8443-exec-10] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp]
2022-05-17 19:55:11.636 DEBUG 19740 --- [io-8443-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
2022-05-17 19:55:11.691 DEBUG 19740 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/favicon.ico", parameters={}
2022-05-17 19:55:11.693 DEBUG 19740 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2022-05-17 19:55:11.694 DEBUG 19740 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2022-05-17 19:55:11.695 DEBUG 19740 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2022-05-17 19:55:11.695 DEBUG 19740 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2022-05-17 19:55:11.695 DEBUG 19740 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2022-05-17 19:55:11.696 DEBUG 19740 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [image/avif, image/webp, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2022-05-17 19:55:11.696 DEBUG 19740 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Tue May 17 19:55:11 IST 2022, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available,  (truncated)...]
2022-05-17 19:55:11.697 DEBUG 19740 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

I am not sure if these require some other sort of wildcards to get it to work. But some pointers would be helpful. Thanks.

EDIT: From what I saw, any URL with index.jsp already in it, doesn't work.

Comment: you're using Spring !!

Comment: @PaulBradbury Yes, I am.

Comment: Please remove all mention of "Spring Boot" - it is different

Comment: Could you elaborate on *what doesn't work*? It doesn't hit the controller? You get an exception? Or what? It is a bit too vague to be able to answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry, I should have mentioned, that

Comment: Is this application deployed on tomcat, or running standalone as a jar (or war)?

Comment: @M.Deinum Its running with the default tomcat provided by spring boot (jar).

Comment: I would suggest to enable DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.web` and see what happens. I suspect something else (tomcat itself maybe) is trying to handle the JSP. You can try to set `server.servlet.register-default-servlet` to `false` in your config (although in newer Spring Boot versions that is already the default).

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated the main question with the logs.

Comment: You want the part before that, as this is the part that redirects to an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is very vague about the issue that you face,

but I will post an issue in your code that definitely will be a bug when you run the application (it can be this the issue that you face as well).

```
@Controller
public class RedirectController {

    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
```

`@Controller` is by default a singleton spring bean. So you could not ask to autowire `HttpServletRequest` since this is a request scope bean.

However you could ask it from spring in the method parameters and this will respect it's scope, since this way each time the method is called in a different request, the object will be passed by spring as parameter to this method.

```
@Controller
public class RedirectController {


    @RequestMapping(value={"/", "/**"})
    public String showRedirectPage(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

        String restOfTheUrl = new AntPathMatcher().extractPathWithinPattern(httpServletRequest.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE).toString(), httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());

        if (restOfTheUrl.contains("ATC") || restOfTheUrl.contains("cds") || restOfTheUrl.contains("cgs") || restOfTheUrl.contains("LOG") || restOfTheUrl.contains("pmm") || restOfTheUrl.contains("appgui") || restOfTheUrl.contains("userfileadmin")) {
            return "redirect";
        } else {            
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

This question contains so many issues, I doubt it is easily solvable in just an answer.

I will point some more errors so that OP could have a direction on how to handle those issues.

1. Spring boot when executed as `jar` has some limitations and can't support `jsp` files. You should try to package the application as `war` and deploy it in some running tomcat.
2. When you fix this you will have to check what you return from the controllers. When you do `return "redirect";` Spring does not know which `jsp` you intend to return so it goes for the default `jsp` with the name `index.jsp` which should exist under `pmm` folder. It would be even better to declare specifically which `jsp` you intend to return so that Spring does not fallback to default functionalities. You could do it like `return "pmm.jsp"`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. But thanks for the info about HttpServletRequest. I have updated my code accordingly.

Comment: @hell_storm2004 check updated answer